# How to open Illustrator file in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

How to open a large Illustrator file (eg. 120 in x 48 in) saved in Illustrator. Then, how to open the same file to actual size in Photoshop?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply go to Photoshop > open > yourfile.ai

It will bring up a window so you see the image size and artboard size. Click ok, and there you have it!

[image: illustrator file in photoshop]

Use this image as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

What about copying the object in illu and paste in your photoshop - Then a dialog like this should appear:

[image: Photoshop Dialog]

Comment: That should be better in english, I guess ...

Comment: really? Smart objekt <> Smart object ? pixel <> pixel ? pfad - okay that maybe tough..but it's path. The real struggle is Formebene, but thats shape(form) layer(ebene)… I guess you are 50% right :p

Answer (score -2):

You might try saving file in EPS format, it must be working.

Good luck